# Can you say why this rotation of a 2D rectangle is not working?

Tags: c++, matrix, rotation, graphics2d

I am using [this BGI library](http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/visual/) from Colorado University to learn the basics of computer graphics.

I took the theory from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations).

You can download the whole VC++ 2008 Express project from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-B-1BTjmHpwbmRrQXdhQW1BRFU/view?usp=sharing).

Translation and Scaling are working. But, the problem is, Rotation operation isn't working.

The output is as follows:
[image]

To me, the correct rotation should be like the following:

[image]

Rotation code is here:

```
#include "graphics.h"
#include "Vector2d.h"
#include "Coordinates2d.h"
#include <math.h>

#define PI      3.14
#define THETA   15.0*PI/180

int main()
{
    Matrix rotMat(3, 3);
    /*
    cos   -sin   0
    sin    cos   0
     0      0    1
    */
    rotMat.SetItem(0, 0, cos(THETA));   rotMat.SetItem(0, 1, -sin(THETA));  rotMat.SetItem(0, 2, 0);
    rotMat.SetItem(1, 0, sin(THETA));   rotMat.SetItem(1, 1, cos(THETA));   rotMat.SetItem(1, 2, 0);
    rotMat.SetItem(2, 0, 0);    rotMat.SetItem(2, 1, 0);    rotMat.SetItem(2, 2, 1);
    rotMat.Show();
    //rotMat.Transpose();
    rotMat.Show();

    //This is a wrapper to display a 2D rectangle.
    Coordinates2d::ShowWindow("Test window");

    Rectangle2d rect(Point2d(0,0), Point2d(150,150));

    Coordinates2d::Draw(rect);  

    Matrix a = rect.Get3x3MatrixStart(); a.Show();
    Matrix b = rect.Get3x3MatrixEnd();b.Show(); 

    a = a.Multiply(rotMat);a.Show();
    b = b.Multiply(rotMat);b.Show();    

    rect.SetStart(a);
    rect.SetEnd(b);

    Coordinates2d::Draw(rect);

    /////////////////////

    while (!kbhit())
    {
        delay(200);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are returning `Matrix` objects by value.  No one knows what your copy constructor looks like, or even more importantly, whether you even need to write one.  A mistake or misstep in this function can make the entire program buggy.  Also, is your issue really a drawing one?  If it is a purely data issue, you don't need BGI or any graphics to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Please add the code to the question, not in the comments.

Comment: You could make things much easier for yourself if you use `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` instead of `double**`.  Then you don't need to write any of those user defined copy constructor or assignment operators.  Also, your implementation of the `Matrix` assignment operator has flaws such as not checking for self-assignment.

Comment: Can you show Matrix Multiply(Matrix&) function body?

Comment: @BROY Look at this implementation of your `MatrixMemory`.  This replaces all of the code you wrote for assignment operator, copy constructor, etc.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/008e804397444f56

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your sin and cos function used to create rotation matrix. Functions sin and cos take as argument angle in radians...

EDIT:

You should also double-check your rotation matrix. In [0,1] should be -sin(theta) and in [1,0] sin(theta). It's standard, but it depends on what rotation you want clockwise or counter-clockwise

Comment: Well, it's working. You rotated vector (150, 150) by 15 degrees anticlockwise. You can check it here: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=rotate+%28150%2C150%29+by+15+degrees+anticlockwise)

Comment: If the current result isn't your goal, then you should describe what output do you expect.

Comment: Well, you should remember that you rotate a **vector** not a point. You cannot rotate point.

But if you really want to rotate a rectangle you should rotate: 
a = (150, 150) - (75, 75) 
and 
b =(0, 0) - (75, 75).
(75,75) is the center of rectangle.
Then new points would be: 
a = rotatedA + (75, 75)
 and 
b = rotatedB + (75, 75)

Comment: So you expect the rombus. You just need to rotate all 4 vertices. So your function which draw only rectangles won't work here.